# How to keep different profiles for running windows services?

Tags: windows-7, services, user-profiles

I am looking for a tool to disable numerous windows services when I need (say I'm developing and need full power, so I can disable Fingerprint services, etc).

I now need to keep track of which ones I disabled, what was their initial startup state, etc. I would have preferred a tool that lets me set different profiles for my windows services ("barebones", "browsing", "programming", etc), which I can activate on demand. Is there something like that?

This is not a one-off thing. I need to switch between different profiles several times a day. So MSConfig, services etc are not useful as they require manual intervention. I need something automated.

I am thinking of making batch files for that unless there is a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried to create different user accounts with different settings depending on what you need?

Comment: Do services depend on user account?

Comment: Hi Jus, recommendation questions are off topic on SU, maybe you are able to rephrase your question? Msconfig would not be suitable?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I asked.  That's why I commented instead of attempting to answer.  Have you tried that?  Let us know.  If nothing else, the next person will be able to know if that works or not.

Comment: Some services are started independently of login, thats why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has become much better over the years at managing services automatically, so in Windows 7 or 8 it should not matter. This provides functional equivalence to using a "RAM booster" program, Register Cleaner Xtreme, going gluten-free w/o celiac disease, or using 'holistic' medicine to treat cancer.

That said, the command as administrator to start / stop a service is net stop/start  for batch files.